# Making Pygame Play Sound ONCE

Tags: python, loops, audio, pygame

I have a small snippet of code which consists of a sound being played once if an if statement is met:

```
for block in block_list:
    if block.rect.y >= 650 and health >=25 and score < 70:
        player_list.remove(player)
        all_sprites_list.remove(player)
        font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
        label = font.render("SCORE TARGET NOT MET", 1, YELLOW)
        labelRect = label.get_rect()
        labelRect.center = (400, 250)

        error.play()
        laser.stop()
```

However upon playing the 'error' sound, it continues to loop until the pygame window is closed. Is there any way I can edit my code so that the 'error' sound effect is only played once?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's played over and over again because the condition of the `if` clause stays `True`; and probably it's `True` for multiple `block` objects in `block_list`.

You should fix that in a way that makes sense for your application.

It's hard to give a good advice when you don't know the bigger picture, but maybe a simple flag will help you:

```
# somewhere
play_error_sound = True

...

for block in block_list:
    if block.rect.y >= 650 and health >=25 and score < 70:
        ...
        if play_error_sound:
            play_error_sound = False
            error.play()

# set play_error_sound to True once it is allowed to be played again
```

---

P.S.: consider loading your `Font` only once at the start of your application, not over and over again in a loop. Also, you should cache all Surfaces created with `font.render`, since font rendering is also a very expensive operation and can be a major performance bottleneck.